# How do I use BottomTab and Stack in the same Project?

Tags: react-native, expo

I built my code using BottomTab but now I need to include a Stack and I don't know which part I should include, I think I'll have to redo the PJ again because it was also giving an error in the stack.

import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Feed from './pages/Feed'
import Profile from './pages/Profile'
import Settings from './pages/Settings';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Routes(){
return (
<Tab.Navigator
screenOptions={{
tabBarActiveTintColor: '#9fe801', //Quando o botão estiver ativo a cor vai ser essa.
tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'white', //Quando o botão estiver desativado a cor vai ser essa.
tabBarShowLabel: false, // some com os nomes abaixo dos icones da barra
tabBarStyle:{
position: 'absolute',
backgroundColor:'#171626',
borderTopWidth: 0,

```
      //bottom: 14 //opcões de estilização da barra 
      //left: 14,
      //right: 14,
      //elevation: 0,
      //borderRadius: 4,
      height: 60,
    }
  }}
  >
    <Tab.Screen
    name='Home'
    component={Home}
    options={{
      headerShown: false, //remove a barra superior com o nome da página
      tabBarIcon: ({color, size, focused}) => {
          if(focused){
            return <Ionicons name = "home" size={size} color
            = {color}/>
          }
          return <Ionicons name = "home-outline" size={size} color
          = {color}/>
      } 
    }}
    />

  <Tab.Screen
    name='Feed'
    component={Feed}
    options={{
      //headerShown: false, //remove a barra superior com o nome da página
      tabBarIcon: ({color, size, focused}) => {
          if(focused){
            return <Ionicons name = "aperture" size={size} color
            = {color}/>
          }
          return <Ionicons name = "aperture-outline" size={size} color
          = {color}/>
      } 
    }}
    />

  <Tab.Screen
    name='Profile'
    component={Profile}
    options={{
      //headerShown: false, //remove a barra superior com o nome da página
      tabBarIcon: ({color, size, focused}) => {
          if(focused){
            return <Ionicons name = "person" size={size} color
            = {color}/>
          }
          return <Ionicons name = "person-outline" size={size} color
          = {color}/>
      } 
    }}
    />

  <Tab.Screen
    name='Settings'
    component={Settings}
    options={{
      //headerShown: false, //remove a barra superior com o nome da página
      tabBarIcon: ({color, size, focused}) => {
          if(focused){
            return <Ionicons name = "settings" size={size} color
            = {color}/>
          }
          return <Ionicons name = "settings-outline" size={size} color
          = {color}/>
      } 
    }}
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>


)
```

}

export default Routes;